# Clash Royale loading problem

Tags: technical-issues, clash-royale

Whenever I open Clash Royale, the progress bar will stop at 50 %, and doesn't go further. I even tried reinstalling the game, but that didn't work. Can somebody tell me how to fix this tricky problem?
I'm playing on an iPhone 8.

Comment: How's your internet? Mine would stop at 50% if I was ever offline or had bad connection.

Comment: I'm using the mobile data, so I don't really think it's a connection problem.

Comment: This is indicative of a network issue.

Comment: I'd try talking to your carrier. Maybe it's something on their end.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear the cache for the game and then open it
if not then clear the cache and reinstall 
---hopes to work fine

Comment: Yep, this worked with me. I own an Android though. But I don't think it should be any different on iOS.(if you are allowed to clear cache that is)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS (expected answer) this may be found from a **bug** or your phone does not meet ping or quality.

## Improvements/Solutions

You can clear your data from the phone, although I do not recommend deleting your game data. Restarting your phone or force stop for a few hours may help with the problem, and if these do not help, do the following:

- Contact Supercell Support
- Contact Apple about the game bug/leave a review on the game (There is a small chance of Supercell responding)

## Common Solutions

Some common solutions to this **without deleting game data** is that you may update your phone on the App Store, or you can just uninstall the game and reinstall it back.

---

## Conclusion

Try all these methods and hopefully one will help the loading screen load to 100% and you can start playing.